# How to print a table on multiple pages in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro in excel which allows me to print one of the tabs in my document. I would like to print a key which I have on the first page on all the other pages aswell without copying & pasting the key into each page. Is it possible to do this? I tried using Page Layout-Page Setup- Print titles but it didn't work out for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best regards,
Ryan Haughey

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/826918/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-the-header-or-the-footer-in-excel or this http://www.guidingtech.com/16117/add-logos-excel-prints-each-page/ ?

Comment: Yes that link sorted me out. Thanks Ralph